# Monkey patch the node js winston logging

Tags: node.js, winston, shimmer

do you have an idea on how to monkey patch the node js winston logging methods like info, debug by using shimmer(https://www.npmjs.com/package/shimmer) ?

For example,
This is my winston 3.x setup:

```
let winston = require('winston')
   winstonInit = winston.createLogger({
      format: winston.format.json(),
      transports: [
        new winston.transports.Console({ level: 'info' }),
        new winston.transports.File({
          name: 'winston-logging',
          level: 'info',
          filename: './log/winston.log',
          handleExceptions: true
        })
      ],
      exceptionHandlers: [
        new winston.transports.File({ filename: './log/exceptions.log', handleExceptions: true})
      ]
    });
    winston.add(winstonInit);
```

So, in my app I can call this
`winston.info('send this message to Slack') // output: send this message to Slack` .Aside from displaying the message, we also perform another functions.

I just want to monkey patch this winston.info() like adding some additional functionality such as sending a Slack message notifications when winston.info was executed. Thanks.

Comment: How have you configured `winston` currently?

Comment: @DhruvShah I've added my winston setup in the summary.

Comment: you can use http transport in winston to send any webpoint.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve this:

A. The `shimmer` way:

```
var shimmer = require('shimmer');

// Assuming that an instance of winston is accesible.
shimmer.wrap(winston, 'info-interceptor', (winstonCall) => {
    return function(arguments) {
        // arguments are the log messages sent to the winston method for logging.
        console.log(arguments)
        
        // check if executed winston function is winston.info or not.
        if(winstonCall.name === 'info'){
           // add logic to send arguments to a slack message
        }
        
        // it is important to return the original call.
        retirm winstonCall;
    }
});
```

Note: Its not advisable to use the `function.name` method, hence I would suggest against using the shimmer way.

B. The `non-shimmer` way

You can update your winston config to execute an additional functionality whenever the info method is executed in the following way:

```
let winston = require('winston')
   winstonInit = winston.createLogger({
      format: winston.format.json(),
      transports: [
        new winston.transports.Console({ level: 'info' }),
        new winston.transports.File({
          name: 'winston-logging',
          level: 'info',
          filename: './log/winston.log',
          handleExceptions: true
        }),
        new HttpStreamTransport({
            url: 'https://yourdomain.com/log'
        })
      ],
      exceptionHandlers: [
        new winston.transports.File({ filename: './log/exceptions.log', handleExceptions: true})
      ]
    });
    
    // winston.add(winstonInit);

    const logger = {
       _sendMessageToSlack: (msg) => {
           // logic for sending message to slack
        
           return message;
       },
       info: (msg) => winstonInit.info(logger._sendMessageToSlack(msg)),
       warn: (msg) => winstonInit.warn(msg),
       error: (msg) => winstonInit.error(msg),
   };

module.exports = logger;
```

This will allow you to import the `logger` instance in various files and use it as `logger.info()`, `logger.warn()`, `logger.error()` and execute the additiona functionality whenever `logger.info` is called.

Comment: Or you may directly use the slack transport available in winston. Reference: https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/blob/master/docs/transports.md#slack-transport

Comment: I've tried in my local using your code in solution A but sorry it is not working. It didn't monkey patch the info method. Your non-shimmer way looks interesting. Thanks  :)